# Obtener los datos de una tabla y pasarlos a Números con JavaScrip

Tags: javascript, jquery

el problema es que no consigo la forma de capturar los datos de cada `td` y poder transformar a números y así hacer operaciones con ellos, en si lo que deseo en teoría es poder sumar los datos de cada columna.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col">colum a</th>
      <th scope="col">colum b</th>
      <th scope="col">colum c</th>
      <th scope="col">colum d</th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>El resultado de la colum a uno es: <p/>
```

gracias de antemano por las ideas que puedan darme.

Comment: ¿El origen de los números debe ser tabla por alguna razon en particular?
¿No te has planteado guardar los números en una matriz, y escribirlos luego en la tabla?

Comment: hola, gracias por responder, el origen de los números vienen de un calculo a través de un valor tomado de un input escrito por el usuario...

Comment: Te recomiendo, que guardes los valores de los inputs en variables, por ejemplo una matriz, en vez de generar directamente el HTML.
Una vez tengas las matriz, puedes hacer con los valores lo que quieras, como realizar cálculos o escribirlos en una tabla HTML.
He respondido a la pregunta para hacerlo como has preguntado, pero hacerlo así seria considerado bastante inadecuado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución es guardar el contenido de cada objeto td en una matriz.

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th scope="col">colum a</th>
      <th scope="col">colum b</th>
      <th scope="col">colum c</th>
      <th scope="col">colum d</th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>El resultado de la colum a uno es: <p/>
<script>
 var numeros=[];
 var tabla=document.getElementsByTagName("td");
 for (var i=0; i<tabla.length; i++){
  numeros.push(parseInt(tabla[i].innerHTML));
 }
 document.write(numeros);
</script>
```

Comment: estupendo, me ha funcionado a la perfeccion, solo cambie el `parseInt` por `parseFloat` y justo lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 1):

He creado un par de funciones que pueden ser de ayuda:

- `calcularSumaColumna`: se le pasa el selector de una tabla y el número de columna que quieres sumar (desde 1 hasta n) y devuelva la suma de los números en la columna indicada (si hay algo que no sea un número se considerará cero).
- `crearFooterTotales`: se le pasa un selector de columna y crea un `tfoot` que se añade a la tabla, con los totales calculados llamando a `calcularSumaColumna`.

Aquí puedes ver las funciones en una demo. Están comentadas para que se entiendan mejor, dime si tienes alguna duda o necesito aclarar algo sobre cómo funcionan:

```js
// función que suma los valores de la columna especificada en la tabla indicada
function calcularSumaColumna(selectorTabla, colnum) {
  var n = parseInt(colnum);
  // seleccionamos todas las celdas de la posicion dada
  var celdas = document.querySelectorAll(selectorTabla + " tbody tr :nth-child(" + n + ")");
  var total = 0;
  // sumamos sus valores (si no son numericos se consideran 0)
  for (var x = 0; x < celdas.length; x++) {
    total += parseInt(celdas[x].innerText) || 0;
  }
  // devolvemos los totales
  return total;
}

// función que crea un foot en la tabla especificada con la suma de los totales
// totales es un booleanoa que indica si la primera columna se sumara (false, por defecto) o no 
function crearFooterTotales(selectorTabla, totales) {
  // inicializar variables auxiliares
  var numCeldas = document.querySelectorAll(selectorTabla + " thead tr th").length;
  var totales = totales || false;
  
  // crear el footer con su fila
  var footer = document.createElement("tfoot");
  var footertr = document.createElement("tr");
  footer.appendChild(footertr);
  // bucle para crear celdas con los totales
  // comienza en 1 porque los indices de CSS empiezan en 1
  for (var x = 1; x <= numCeldas; x++) {
    var celda = document.createElement("td");
    if (totales && x == 1) {
      celda.textContent = "TOTAL";
    } else {
      celda.textContent = calcularSumaColumna(selectorTabla, x);
    }
    footertr.appendChild(celda);
  }
  // añadir el footer a la tabla
  document.querySelector(selectorTabla).appendChild(footer);
}

crearFooterTotales(".table", true);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">colum a</th>
      <th scope="col">colum b</th>
      <th scope="col">colum c</th>
      <th scope="col">colum d</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>El resultado de la columa uno es:
  <p/>
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, implemente la del footer, estupendo. Agradecida.